# How to customize Acumatica string field into stringlist?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to customize the CustRefNbr field on the sales order entry screen to be a stringlist by overriding in the SOOrderEntry code.  However, I am getting error:

\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(55): error CS0103: The name 'CustomerRefNbr' does not exist in the current context

```
#region CustomerRefNbr
[PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "External Reference")]
[PXStringList(
    new string[]
{
CustomerRefNbr.Email,
CustomerRefNbr.Phone,
CustomerRefNbr.Web,
CustomerRefNbr.Notification
},
new string[]
{
"Email",
"Phone",
"Web",
"Notification"
})]
protected virtual void SOOrder_CustomerRefNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  Forgot to add this part:

public static class CustomerRefNbr
{

```
public const string Email = "EMAIL";
public const string Phone = "PHONE";
public const string Web = "WEB";
public const string Notification = "NOTIFICATION";
```

}